# Strange behavior with element ids in ie8

Tags: javascript

Why does this work in ie8?

```
function testFunction(ctrl)
{
                alert(ctrl.value);
}
```

I have a javascript function on my page like so.  I then have a input tag with an id of "text1" and a button with the following onclick event

```
<input id="text1" value="value" />

<input type="submit" onclick="testFunction(text1)" value="Click" />
```

the javascript function does indeed alert the value of the textbox, but i am just passing in the id of the textbox, unquoted. I dont have to call getelementbyid, it just works.  What is ie doing here, it doesnt work in firefox.  How does the id turn into the actual textbox object, and i can call cntrl.value on it?

P.S.  - I know I shouldn't user the onclick handler in this way, just an easy way to illustrate the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a side effect of your page probably being on quirks mode and IE doing nasty DOM Level 0 stuff.

The actual explanation is that on DOM Level 0 elements with an ID get automagically added to the `window` global object, and in consequence automagic variables are getting created on the global scope that point towards your DOM element.

Long story short: don't code like that, *ever*. You are relying on a 'de-facto' standard where browsers usually try to imitate what the other does, and this is a case where IE behaves really bad and other browsers didn't follow suit. Use actual DOM methods where suitable, like `getElementById` in this case.

Comment: Agreed. A further note: this use of ids directly in code rather than using getElementById() is the sort ot thing you used to see all the time in the really early days of JavaScript on the web, a practice that was encouraged at the time by some of the dodgy "How to write JavaScript" websites that were around then. (Not like *now*, when 100% of "How to write JavaScript" websites give 100% accurate advice.) (I wish.)

Comment: very nearly a -1. Nothing to do with DOM 0, everything to do with proprietary IE behaviour. DOM 0 was stuff that was *common* between browsers but outside DOM 1.

Comment: yeah, probably more of a DOM 0+. It's a quirk from the same era where DOM 1 wasn't yet done, but still works like DOM 0 given that it's an auto-mapping done by the browser that lets you access elements without using any formal API.

Answer (score 0):

The `ctrl.value` syntax is used for a HTML element with the `name` attribute set to "ctrl". It is not standard that it is used for `id`. You have to use `getElementById` for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from gonchuki answer. This is how your should be doing it.

```
function testFunction(ctrl)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(ctrl);
    alert(obj.value);
}

<input type="submit" onclick="testFunction('text1')" value="Click" />
```

Also there is nothing wrong with using the onclick event of a button. That is what it is there for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ash Burlaczenko, although I know how to use getElementById, I was just curious why ie worked without it.  Also, I don't think there is anything wrong with using the onclick event, but I dont like using inline events like my above example, much prefer to attach event handlers in javascript.